# Can not use component in active -hdl 10

Tags: components, vhdl, fpga, active-hdl

I use `active-hdl 10` for compile and simulation a DFlipFlop structural.
my code compiled successfully without any error or warning but when I simulate it,  my output have unknown value .(see picture)

[image]
(click to enlarge)

I compile and simulate this code in `xilinx` and `active-hdl 8` without any problem.

D_FlipFlop code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity D_FlipFlop is
Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Q : inout  STD_LOGIC);
end D_FlipFlop;

architecture Behavioral of D_FlipFlop is
component DLach Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC;
                          C : in  STD_LOGIC;
                          Q : inout  STD_LOGIC;
                          Qprim : inout  STD_LOGIC);                            

end component;                                                
Signal Y : STd_logic;
Signal Clk_Not : Std_Logic;
Signal out1 : Std_Logic;
Signal out2 : Std_Logic;
begin
Clk_Not<=not(clk);
h1 : DLach port map(D=>D,C=>clk,Q=>Y,Qprim=>out1);
h2 : DLach port map(Y,Clk_Not,Q,out2);
end Behavioral;
```

Dlach code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity DLach is
Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC;
       C : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Q : inout  STD_LOGIC:= '0';
       Qprim : inout  STD_LOGIC:= '1');
end DLach;

architecture Behavioral of DLach is

Signal first : Std_logic ;
Signal second : Std_logic ;
Signal D_not : Std_logic ;

begin      

D_Not <= not(D);

first <= D Nand C;
second <= D_not nand C;

Q <= first nand Qprim;
Qprim <= second nand Q ;

end Behavioral;
```

---

I research a lot but I cant find the answer.
so I think this dosent work for who they use trial version of active -hdl.

Comment: Then initialize the values.

Comment: I try it but nothing change. I know my component don't work (see picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search a lot about this problem, it seems no one appear with this problem. so I think this problem occured on trial version of `active -hdl 10` or cracked versions.